# Django-admin creates a django 1.8 project, but I installed django 1.11.2

Tags: python, python-3.5, django-1.11

I'm a beginner in django..

I am trying to build an application using django 1.11.2 and python 3.5.2, both are installed. I have python 2.7 installed too.

I have executed this command: `django-admin startproject Application1` to create a new application.

The application runs, but the project is versioned Django 1.8, however when I run `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` to find django version, it shows 1.11.2

The command `django-admin --version` shows me 1.8.7

What's wrong?

Do I have two django installed versions?

Should I upgrade django-admin? How?

Please, help me.. I'm stuck.

Comment: You might want to try "which django-admin" to understand where the command is comming from. probably the 2.7 and not the python 3.5.2.  might be pathing issue.  Also you might check out virtualenv,  it will let you define virtual python environments that each have their own set of plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have two django installed on your system: in your python2 environment and python3 environment. So, what you have to do is to uninstall one of them so they won't be conflicted. Since you want to use python3 as your environment, you should uninstall django in your python2 environment with the following command:

```
pip uninstall django
```

If it says, "command not found" after you uninstall it, try to reinstall django with the following command

```
pip3 install django
```